# Kile: How to spell check all files in a project? (recursive spell-checker?)

Tags: kile, spelling, proofreading

When I write a paper using Kile, I typically create a project for the paper, have each section of the paper in a separate file in the project, and use the `\include` command to order them in the document.

I usually have automatic spell checking turned off because the wiggly lines annoy me.  Instead, I simply manually run the spell checker periodically.  However, whenever I do this, I have to open every file I want to spell check and run the spell checker in each one.  This can get a bit annoying as I sometimes have dozens of files to spell check.

**Is there a way to do either of the following:**

1. Spell check all files in a Kile project
2. "Recursively" spell check files by opening and spell checking files listed in `\include` commands?

Comment: I think this is a missing feature for Kile.
FWIW, i just filed an enhancement request:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=287746

Comment: @AlessandroC. Would you turn the comment into an answer?

Comment: @egreg Done! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a missing feature for Kile. FWIW, i just filed an [enhancement request](http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=287746).

Comment: Accepting this answer for the time being since it is unfortunately the answer to my question.  Hopefully this can be edited in the near future to explain kile's new recursive spell check feature.